# how to specify codec in m3u8 while creating segments using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I am using ffmpeg to create a HLS playlist using segment filter.

```py
    result = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg -y -i {}  -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time {} -segment_list {}.m3u8 {}%03d.ts'.format(pathToDownloadedMediaFile, 10, mediaFileName,mediaFileName)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

the generated file is :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128000.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128001.ts
#EXTINF:9.984000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128002.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128003.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128004.ts
#EXTINF:9.984000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128005.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128006.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128007.ts
#EXTINF:9.984000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128008.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128009.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128010.ts
#EXTINF:9.984000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128011.ts
#EXTINF:10.008000,
c1dcf7f6643551fc22b82978d31f746fc40ed69d-128012.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

As you can see, in the EXTINF tag, there is no CODEC specified,

it is required for using `setAllowChunklessPreparation(true)` in the exoplayer in Android for faster playback.

does anyone have idea how can i set the codec while generating the m3u8 manifest.

Comment: I think you need to specify `-master_pl_name`, which will reference this playlist and will also contain `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` with `CODECS`.

Comment: thanks, i missed it in docs.